# Check "Required" via Javascript or JS-event when form is really submitted?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web-application where I display a "processing request" overlay to lock the UI while the server (=embedded device => SLOW) is processing the request which I trigger when the submit button is pressed.
Now I have the problem, that some inputs have the `required="required"` attribute set and if such an input is empty my overlay locks the screen and in the background you can see the "This field is required" message without a chance to fill it out, because of the overlay.

Is there a way to detect for such inputs via javascript "automatically" (meaning without itterating over all inputs and checking the content manually) or is there a better place to trigger my overlay, like when the form is rally submitted to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML5 forms and form elements has a method `checkValidity()`.
But only supported in modern browsers. If you want fallback, go with @Ved's answer.
Read more @ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Forms_in_HTML)

Comment: This was exactly what I search for. The browsers who support the `required` attribute should also support the `checkValidity()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Before you submit the form, all the inputs of the form should be validated FIRST. If this validation succeeds, then only you should show overlay. So, just put your showing overlay code under the validation part (which is displaying message of "required field").

Hope this helps.